# Feature extraction in LSTM model as custom layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, feature-extraction

I defined custom function to train LSTM model with Tensorflow. I would like to preprocess data and do feature extraction right in model, because i want to use model on mobile device, so i do not need to write feature extraction on my own for mobile device. Here is my function:

```
def evaluate_model_extraction(trainX, trainy, testX, testy):
    verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 15, 64
    n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = (
        trainX.shape[1],
        trainX.shape[2],
        trainy.shape[1],
    )

    history = []

    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(40, 51))
    embedding = landmarks_to_embedding_lstm(inputs)

    layer = LSTM(
        64, input_shape=(embedding.shape[1], embedding.shape[2]), return_sequences=True
    )(embedding)
    layer = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(layer)
    layer = LSTM(64)(layer)
    layer = Dropout(0.2)(layer)
    layer = Dense(16, activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3))(layer)
    outputs = Dense(n_outputs, activation="softmax")(layer)

    model_lstm = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    model_lstm.summary()

    model_lstm.compile(
        optimizer="adam",
        loss="categorical_crossentropy",
        metrics=["accuracy"],
    )

    history = model_lstm.fit(
        trainX, trainy, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose
    )

    # evaluate model
    _, accuracy = model_lstm.evaluate(testX, testy)
    return accuracy
```

It works well with CNN model:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(51))
embedding = landmarks_to_embedding(inputs)

layer = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu6)(embedding)
layer = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(layer)
layer = keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu6)(layer)
layer = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(layer)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(len(preprocessor.class_names()), activation="softmax")(
    layer
)

model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.summary()
```

But when i try to call function for train LSTM, i get an error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [64,1,17,2] vs. [2560,40,17,2]
     [[node model_4/tf.broadcast_to_8/BroadcastTo (defined at tmp/ipykernel_1362529/2366185540.py:47) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_470118]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

trainX shape is (314, 40, 51) and trainy is (314, 2). Problem is, that during training, there is a shape of [64,1,17,2] and it doesnt fit batch size of 40 frames ([2560,40,17,2] shape). How to make it work together?

Comment: What types of layers are landmarks_to_embedding and landmarks_to_embedding_lstm?
Could you provide the summary of the models?

Comment: they are custom functions to extract features from input tensor (x,40,51). landmarks_to_embedding_lstm preprocess data and extract features to shape (x,40,34).